# jQuery / javascript resolve virtual address to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, resolveurl

I am trying to load a partial view based on the current selected value in a dropdown list.
My code works when I hard code the url...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#accountDropdownList').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#addressDetails').html('').load("http://localhost:52477/Account/Details/", { id: value }, function (data) { });

        return;
    });
});
```

but I want to use a virtual address like in my asp.net mvc 3 in c# views

```
@Html.Action("Details", "Account", new { id = value })
```

Is there anyway to resolve the controller and method names to a complete url?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use also relative path: .load("/Account/Details/", { id: value }, function (data) { });

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I did how ever try this before and it returned http://localhost:52477/Invoice/Edit/1/Account/Details/ rather than  http://localhost:52477/Account/Details/ so dont know what i did wrong the first time.